# Prevent scroll to top on model update Angular 8

Tags: scroll, angular8

I need to prevent scrolling to top on model update in angular 8 app. 
I've tried saving scroll position and scrolling back to it after update, but this is visible to user and not good. I need a page to stay at the same place or getting back to it smoothly and quick. 
I've also tried having the full model from the start to avoid updating it, but it is still needed in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrollIntoView:

```
@ViewChild("myElem") myElementToScroll: ElementRef; 
this.myElementToScroll.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  I had to remove the scrollOptions though. (*shrug*)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your routing.  You might have a scroll to top in there.  I am working in Angular 8, and my app doesn't scroll to the top on model update.